Looking for a Microsoft Graph API that can update device ownership of a deivce
I am looking to update device ownership of a device in AAD using Microsoft Graph API
This closest I have come to is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/device-post-registeredowners?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp but this needs delegated permission.
I would like to do it directly using Application permission type because I have to do the ownership change using a background process without any user involvement.
Note: My devices are not managed by In-tune
I have tried looking for APIs but I was not very successful. I got it working by using new GraphServiceClient(new InteractiveBrowserCredential()); graph api client but it needs user input which is a no for my user case

Hi @Vishal, Have you tried this API call? You can use the Device.ReadWrite.All permission to your app and update deviceOwnership property. Let me know if this works.

AFAIK it is not possible to update device ownership of a device in AAD using application permissions. By default you need to use delegated permission with user interactive flow

I got the error when I tried to registered owner of the device using application Api permissions via clientSecretCredential:
class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string clientId = "ClientID";
        string tenantId = "TenantID";
        string clientSecret = "Secret";

        string deviceId = "DeviceID";
        string ownerId = "OwnerID"; 

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret);
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential);

        try
        {

            var ownerReference = new ReferenceCreate
            {
                OdataId = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{ownerId}"
            };

            await graphClient.Devices[deviceId].RegisteredOwners.Ref.PostAsync(ownerReference);
            Console.WriteLine("User added as a registered owner successfully.");
        }
        catch (ODataError odataError)
        {
            
            Console.WriteLine($"OData Error: {odataError.Error?.Message}");
            if (odataError.Error?.InnerError != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error Code: {odataError.Error?.Code}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}



Note that: Application permissions are not supported to add a user as a registered owner of the device and there is no other use application Api permission.


Hence, you need to mandatorily make use of delegated permissions with user interactive only like below:

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string clientId = "ClientID";
        string deviceId = "DeviceID";
        string ownerId = "OwnerID";

        // Use InteractiveBrowserCredential for interactive login
        var interactiveCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential();
        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(interactiveCredential);

        try
        {
            var ownerReference = new ReferenceCreate
            {
                OdataId = $"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/directoryObjects/{ownerId}"
            };

            await graphClient.Devices[deviceId].RegisteredOwners.Ref.PostAsync(ownerReference);
            Console.WriteLine("User added as a registered owner successfully.");
        }
        catch (ODataError odataError)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"OData Error: {odataError.Error?.Message}");
            if (odataError.Error?.InnerError != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error Code: {odataError.Error?.Code}");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}



Reference:
Create registeredOwner - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft
